# Display certain version of adaptive icon as ImageView on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

When adding an adaptive icon to an `ImageView` in an Activity in Android, it seems to adopt the same version as OEM design. In my case right now this is the rounded version. But I want to display this as an icon in my main activity and thus want to use for example the square version with rounded corners. If this is possible, how can I achieve this? If this is not possible I can create a new resource, but it needs to use `ic_launcher_background` and `ic_launcher_foreground` so that the icon is not defined in multiple places.

This is my `ic_launcher.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

This is my `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Before telling the solution directly, you'd know how system draw an adaptive icon in a image view. It mainly contains three steps.

1. Draw a background.
2. Draw a foreground.
3. Set a transparent area with a mask.

If you put an adaptive icon into an `ImageView`, this steps will be completed automatically. Hence there will be a system defined mask on that. So your question is how to draw a customized mask there. Then let's see how we can achieve this.

1. Get the adaptive drawable as well as its layers.

```
    Drawable rawDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, null);
    Drawable foreground = rawDrawable.getForeground();
    Drawable background = rawDrawable.getBackground();
```

2. Create a bitmap with a customized size.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSize, bitmapSize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

3. Create a `Canvas` used for drawing drawable layers.

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

4. Draw the layers.

```
    background.setBounds(0, 0, bitmapSize, bitmapSize);
    background.draw(canvas);
    foreground.setBounds(0, 0, bitmapSize, bitmapSize);
    foreground.draw(canvas);
```

5. After step 4, you will get an icon as a square version. And if you need to add round corners to it. You need to draw the mask yourself.

```
    Bitmap maskBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapSize, bitmapSize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas maskCanvas = new Canvas(maskBitmap);

    Paint xferPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    xferPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    xferPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    maskCanvas.drawRoundRect(0,0,bitmapSize, bitmapSize, 12, 12, xferPaint);

    xferPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0, 0, xferPaint);
```

6. Then put the bitmap into the `ImageView`,

```
    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```